# python functions, math between csv files

Tags: python, function

I have a function that reads a csv file and then finds the average of specific values. I want to use this function to read two separate csv files and then find the average between the csv files. How would I do this since the function does not create a variable? Can you do something like this in a loop?

I know the last line doesn't make any sense, but that's essentially what I'm trying to do...

```
import csv
import math

def read_file(file):
    with open(file, 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
        temperatures = []
        for row in reader:
            if(row[2] == date):
                temperatures.append(float(row[3]))
        print(sum(temperatures)/len(temperatures))

read_file('temp1.csv')
read_file('temp2.csv')

bay_temp = (read_file('temp1.csv')+ read_file('temp2.csv'))/2
print bay_temp
```

Comment: Where does `date` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result.

Change:

```
print(sum(temperatures)/len(temperatures))
```

in:

```
return sum(temperatures)/len(temperatures)
```

If the function worked before, it should give you the average temperature.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use the built in mean() function and store it in a variable. This could be a good situation to use Pandas as it can read CSV files and extract just the columns or data you need into a dataframe or series and then use statistic functions on the data, such as mean(). This may not be the best statistical use but it is an idea of how to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

file1_average = file1['column_name'].mean()
file2_average = file2['column_name'].mean()

average = (file1_average + file2_average) / 2

return average
```